# Sqlite epoch datetime conversion

Tags: c#, sqlite

So I'm trying to convert epoch time from a sqlite database. I am using the time column the type is Timeswap.

The value stored is: 1383928265 (11/8/2013 11:31:05 AM) http://www.epochconverter.com/

The SQL:

```
var sql = "SELECT session_id, xml, strftime('%s',stopped), strftime('%s',time), orig_title FROM processed";
```

The result: 119360752804800 (10/13/1973 7:45:52 AM)

My converter:

```
    public static DateTime FromUnixTime(long unixTime)
    {
        var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return epoch.AddSeconds(unixTime).ToLocalTime();
    }
```

I made some adjustments to the converter:

```
    public static DateTime FromUnixTime(long unixTime)
    {
        var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var s = unixTime / 86400;
        return epoch.AddSeconds(s).ToLocalTime();
    }
```

But it's yielding: 10/11/2013 6:34:37 AM

I cannot get the correct date from the sqlite database.

EDIT:
schema

[image: SQLite schema]

Comment: Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: So you say that you store epoch time in database, then in select you call strftime to calculate from it epoch again? I think you should not use strftime in your query.

Comment: In addition to @Mateusz comment, can you show us the scheme of the table? in what sort of field are you saving the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [strftime](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) wrong.
A number is interpreted as a Julian date unless you use the `unixepoch` modifier:

```sql
> SELECT strftime('%s', 1383928265), datetime(1383928265);
119360535336000  3784354-44914542-14 12:00:00
> SELECT strftime('%s', 1383928265, 'unixepoch'), datetime(1383928265, 'unixepoch');
1383928265       2013-11-08 16:31:05
```

However, the value in the database already has the exact format that you want, so you do not need to use `strftime` in the first place:

```sql
SELECT session_id, xml, stopped, time, orig_title FROM processed
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply! The reason I am using strftime is because when I run the query string in C# The sqlite connector lib tells me "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.". So I was attempting to use strftime without fully understanding its function.